Widget with image in masonary grid causes resize after loading image
I'm using the Masonry grid from the flutter_staggered_grid_view  package along with cached_network_image to display images fetched from an API. When the grid is initially displayed, the images are still being loaded from the network, and regardless of how fast the images load (even if they are cached), the widget appears to resize itself as each image is fetched and rendered.
Is there a way to prevent the widget from resizing itself during the image loading process or any good idea how to make that transition smooth?
I tried to mask the resizing issue by adding animations, which helped a bit, but it still bothers me. I also considered assigning fixed sizes to the widget, but that somewhat defeats the purpose of using the Masonry grid.
Example of widget:
  CupertinoButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: 'url',
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 8),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'test',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'some text',
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'some text',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );



while this is not a perfect solution but it could help a bit to improve
You can use Predefine Placeholer to handle initial size, and here you also need to add error handling
AnimatedSize(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
  child: CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: 'url',
    placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 200, // Fixed height during loading
      color: Colors.grey[300],
    ),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 200, // Fixed height for error
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Icon(Icons.error),
    ),
  ),
),

now it's upto you, show an error image or an unsized SizedBox so if an image get's crashed while fetching will not consume even an pixle for that you can use SizedBox.shrink()

The resizing issue has been reduced, but the widget still resizes slightly when the image loads.. because some images are smaller and some have bigger height so after load there is still same effect

there is no proper solution for this because how we can get idea for the dimension of upcoming images, especially in specific manner
i am updating to make it animated for smoothness

I may have found a solution via trial and error. Here is the code I used in FlutterFlow under a widget. It works around the image dimensions and resizes with minimal effect. (With some FlutterFlow intervention on the code as it didn't fit protocols and legislations apparently.)
class NewCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewCustomWidget({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  });

  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  State<NewCustomWidget> createState() => _NewCustomWidgetState();
 }

  class _NewCustomWidgetState extends State<NewCustomWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

